# AngularJS Leaflet plot and remove markers via options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have something that look like below, and when a user clicks on "View on Map" it changes to "Remove Markers". So the problem I am having now is that, when a user clicks on all three View on Map items, how do I store each of them in different layers so that when "Remove Markers" is pressed, it would remove its own layer. And I have my code stored in ng-repeat.

[image]

As you can see from my JavaScript code, I'm storing them all in the same layer and removing the layer when "Remove Marker" pressed which removes all the points and ruin my code too. Any way to store them in different layer or other method in doing this?

```
 $scope.getMapData = function (msg, passedIndex) {
                map.addLayer(cities);

                $scope.Lng.length = 0;
                $scope.Lat.length = 0;
                $scope.dataLatLng.length = 0;

               queryNameUrl = 'https://developers.onemap.sg/publicapi/themeapi/retrieveTheme?queryName=' + msg +
               '&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjMsInVzZXJfaWQiOjMsImVtYWlsIjoicHVibGljQXBpUm9sZUBzbGEuZ292LnNnIiwiZm9yZXZlciI6ZmFsc2UsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL29tMi5kZmUub25lbWFwLnNnXC9hcGlcL3YyXC91c2VyXC9zZXNzaW9uIiwiaWF0IjoxNTQwOTI5OTE2LCJleHAiOjE1NDEzNjE5MTYsIm5iZiI6MTU0MDkyOTkxNiwianRpIjoiYjVkNmZkNGJhOWJiNGJiM2FkNWQzN2ZhNTAzMGIxYWEifQ.YQdfV43wrg8dX-He7-mwIL2Qhjsexq0tgNu5RotAdu4';
               $http.get(queryNameUrl).then(function(response) {
                 $scope.apiResult = response.data.SrchResults;
                 $scope.apiResult.splice(0,1);
                 $scope.cnmoh = true;

                       for (var i= 0; i < $scope.apiResult.length; i++) {
                            if ($scope.apiResult[i].Type == "Point"){
                              $scope.apiResult[i].visibility = true;
                              $scope.dataLatLng.push($scope.apiResult[i].LatLng)
                              $scope.Lat.push($scope.dataLatLng[i].split(',')[0]);
                              $scope.Lng.push($scope.dataLatLng[i].split(',')[1]);
                              L.marker([$scope.Lat[i], $scope.Lng[i]], {icon: greenIcon}).bindPopup($scope.apiResult[i].DESCRIPTION).addTo(cities);
                            }
                              // else if ($scope.apiResult[i].Type == "Polygon"){
                              //       $scope.PolyLine.push($scope.apiResult[i].LatLng)
                              //       console.log($scope.PolyLine)
                              //       // for (var i = 0; i < $scope.PolyLine.length; i++) {
                              //       //     $scope.polyLineCord.push($scope.PolyLine[i])
                              //       //     // console.log($scope.polyLineCord)
                              //       // }
                              //   }
                       }
               })
               if($scope.community[passedIndex].visibility)
                {
                  $scope.community[passedIndex].visibility = false;
                }
               else{

                 $scope.community[passedIndex].visibility = true;
                 $scope.stored = $scope.community[passedIndex];
               }
        }


          $scope.removeMarker = function (passedIndex) {
          if($scope.community.visibility)
           {
             $scope.community.visibility = true;
           } else {
                cities.clearLayers();
                $scope.stored.visibility = false;
              }
          }
```

Map JS:

```
       var cities = L.layerGroup();

    var basemap   = L.tileLayer('https://maps-{s}.onemap.sg/v3/Default/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      detectRetina: true,
      maxZoom: 15,
      minZoom: 11
    });

    var center = L.bounds([1.56073, 104.21475], [1.16, 103.502]).getCenter();
    var map = L.map('mapdiv', {
      center: [center.x, center.y],
      zoom: 12,
      layers: [basemap, cities]
    });

    map.setMaxBounds([[1.49073, 104.2147], [1.16, 103.582]]);
    var baseLayers = {
      "BaseMap": basemap,
    };

    var overlays = {
      "Cities": cities,
    };

    L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);
```